# Can Multiple Asian "Border Hops" Negatively Effect Canadian Visitor Visa Application

Tags: visas, canada, thailand, tourist-visas

Ok so I am appllying for a Canadian visitor visa onlline to go and visit a friend for 2-weeks. I have uploaded all my documents, and carefully examined eachone. Everything looks good EXCEPT:

### TRAVEL HISTORY

There is a section where you should upload ALL pages in your passport with visas, stamps, entries etc.

I have lived in Thailand for a period of 2-years and have burned through 2 passports doing border hops every 3-months since temporarily leaving my country in Aug 2015. All border hops were done to obtain a new tourist visa. I may have engaged in some freelance employment or I may not have....but guess that is out of scope of question

I have recently secured a good job which provided me with a year visa until Jun 2018 in Thailand.

**Question:**

- Do I really have to upload each page with visas, which  resullts in nearlly 30 pages?
- What would happen if I just upload my current active passport with work visa (best guess)
- PRIMARY QUESTION: **Can all these border bounces I did to countries like Laos & Cambodia for nearly 2-years count against me when applying for a visitor visa?** *I should add I have never overstayed a visa so can it perhaps count in my favor?*

Any help / advice appreciated

Comment: What sort of entries or visa were you using to live in Thailand?

Comment: @Tom don't get why this question got down voted....Tourist Visas

Comment: Your record of living in Thailand under the radar by making visa runs, may be taken into consideration by the consular staff when looking at your request.

Comment: In my opinion, you were living in Thailand, and using visa runs to extend your time in Thailand, when you should've been using a different type of visa.  This will be held against you.  The Canadian ECOs will be thinking that you're meaning to stay in Canada (perhaps illegally)

Comment: @MatthewBarclay I think you are wrong. I got a 10-year visa went to Canada and it was pretty sweet. The multiple visas did raise suspiction though and I got held for, wait for this....2-hours checking if I was involved in any sex trafficking. Was horrible but rather funny thinking back